# How to call an open data element with python?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, csv, jupyter

I generated code that saves data from an array to a file as follows:

```
with open(path + '/data_Sevol.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
     fieldnames = ['Sevol']
     writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
     writer.writeheader()
     for i in range(len(Sevol)):
         writer.writerow({'Sevol': Sevol[i].tolist()})
```

In a jupyter notebook I opened this file with the commands:

```
directory = os.getcwd()
path = os.path.join(directory, name_folder)

with open(path + str("\\") + str("data_Sevol.csv"), 'r') as file:
    data_Sevol = csv.reader(file)
    for row in data_Sevol:
        print(row)
```

However, when I try to call an element from the list (`data_Sevol[1][1]`, for example) it gives an error.

```
-------------------------------------------------- -------------------------
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [24], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 data_Sevol[0][1]

TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable
```

The best way to fix this is to fix the way I saved the `data_Sevol.csv` file or fix the way I opened it in the new notebook?

Obs:  I need elements to be printed as numbers and not as strings

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`data_Sevol` is not a list it is a `_csv.reader` object. While it is iterable (`for row in data_Sevol:` works) it is not subscriptable (`data_Sevol[1]` doesn't work). You can fix it with

```
data_Sevol = list(data_Sevol)
```

Then `data_Sevol[1]` should work.

Note: you need to do conversion before the for loop, otherwise you'll "consume" the `data_Sevol` reader and the list will end up empty.

Comment: It still gives an error: ```ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [35], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 data_Sevol = list(data_Sevol)

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.```

Comment: Have you done it inside `with open(...)` before the `for row in data_Sevol:`?